# How to update an old pod, for cocoapods?

Tags: cocoapods

### Question

If you pushed a `pod` on `cocoapods` with the old process, how to update it (with the new process)?

### Details

By old process, I mean with `github` and `Pull Requests`.

By new process, I mean the new way of updating pods, such as described [here](http://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to be followed:

- Claim your pod: https://trunk.cocoapods.org/claims/new. **Do it again**. If it is already done, it will tell you what is the email associated with this pod.
- Trunk register your computer : `$ pod trunk register YOUR_MAIL@COMPANY.COM  'your name' --description='macbook pro'` and click on the link sent by email to confirm. **Be sure to put the same email** as the one used for claiming (so, that's why you should do the provisos step).
- Go the directory of your pod. Update it if necessary, and tag the last version on `github` (same version number as in the `podspec`).
- Then `$ pod lib lint` to check the syntax, etc. of your pod. I don't know if this can be overpass.
- Then, finally `$ pod trunk push YourPod.podspec`.

It worked with my pod, hope it will work for you !